# SQL Server - Automatically Calculate total every day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job

I need to keep a daily statistic of the count of records in a table.

Is there a way to automate counting the records daily and writing the result into another table? Maybe using a SQL Agent Job or something like that?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thank you!

**Edit:**
If I delete today all records from 1/1/2010, the statistic still needs to show that at 1/1/2010 there were 500 records at the end of the day. So solely using GetDate() and summing up doesn't work, as I'd get 0 records with that method for 1/1/2010.

Answer (score 2):

Add a column to your table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE My_Table
ADD insert_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

You can then query against that as SQL intended.

Comment: @Alex: Then remove DELETE access, and use a STATUS_TYPE_CODE table & foreign key to mark such records as DELETED...

Comment: Can't do this. Changing the method of deleting is out of my scope and would break legacy compatibility.

Comment: If that's a concern, then yes you could set up a job to do that in SQL Server. It should be pretty straight forward. Or, as OMG Ponies suggests, use logical deletes instead of physical deletes. It's more to set up since it might require application changes, but it may be a good idea even outside of this one particular requirement.

Comment: @Alex: <homer>Awwww, crap...</homer>

Answer (score 2):

Insert trigger: update counting table record for today (insert if not already created)
Delete trigger: decrement counting table record for today (insert if not already created)

Comment: +1: Based on clarified requirements, better than SQL Agent Job

Comment: Why potentially update a table 1000 times in a day, rather than just get the count once at the end of the day? The trigger method also seems more error-prone to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you answered your own question with the best option. Create a Job that just calls a stored procedure getting the count and stamping them.

The other option mentioned by Tom H. is a better choice, but If you can't alter the table for whatever reason the job is a good option.

Another option could be to place an insert trigger on that table to increment a count somewhere, but that could affect performance depending on how you implement it.

Setting up the job is simple through the SQL Management studio interface with a schedule of how often to run and what stored procedure to call. You can even just write the command directly in the command window of the step instead of calling a sp.

Answer (score 1):

Tom's answer with OMG_Ponies' addendum about tombstoning instead of deleting is the best answer. If you are concerned about how many records *were* in the table on a certain day, there is a good possibility that someone one day will ask for information *about* those records on that day.

If that is a no go, then as others have said, create a second table with a field for the PK of the last record for the day, and then count for the day, then create a job that runs at the end of each day and counts all records with OrginalTable.PK > MAX(NewCountTable.Last_PK_Field) and adds that row (Last_PK_Field, Count) to the NewCountTable.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Job is good -- yes.

Or you could add a date column to the table defaulted to GETDATE().  This wouldn't work if you don't want your daily counts to be affected by folks deleting records after the fact.